# Paypal - Decreasing Recurring Payment Profile Amount

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, express-checkout, paypal-nvp

Is it possible to decrease the recurring payment amount/rate using NVP API Operation for a recurring payment profile created using Express Checkout ?

I read [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/), merchant can increase the amount by 20% of the original amount every 180 days from the profile started date. 
However, it does not mention about decreasing the amount.

I know it is possible to do it manual through Paypal Interface. I have tested this in Sandbox environment.

In our flow, one recurring payment profile can accommodate more than one item/service. So if one of the services is un-subscribed, we have to decrease the amount of the corresponding profile.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it works fine, but it's been a while since I've done that specifically.  You can easily test that in the sandbox, though.

Comment: Hello @andrew,

I am also facing the same problem, I also want to reduce the amount. I am using UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile it changes the SubscriberName but does not make any effect on amount. Can you explain if you have any idea?

Comment: @Rav'sPatel Any updates on this? How did you implement it?